# GLM in R dummy variables, do i need to specify factor?

Tags: r, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model

I am creating a glm where sex is one of the predictors.  I have already coded it such that 0=male and 1= female.  Do I need to specify the variable as a factor when creating the glm?  How do I interpret the output?

Comment: The tutorial at http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm may be helpful.

Comment: If your variable `sex` is already binary, no, you won't need to code it as factor. There are some advantages though regarding the use of factors with linear models in R, namely the specification of contrasts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you need to specify that the variable is a factor, otherwise R will treat it as a numeric variable. Use `as.factor` to do this or `factor` to also specify labels. The first level of the factor is typically treated as the reference category (in your case 0, or male). So the output in a glm (assuming you mean a logistic regression model, link function = logit) can be interpreted as the log odds difference between males and females in your response variable.

As this is difficult to interpret I suggest using `exp`to transform your regression coefficient from log odds to odds so you can interpret it as the odds ratio between males and females. The interpretation would be: 'females are `exp(coefficient)` times more likely to have success in the dependent variable than males'. Success is defined by scoring a 1 on your dependent variable.

Edit: in case of a binary predictor, the model estimates are the same for a numeric as factor version.

Comment: I don't think factorization is needed when the categorical variable is binary as in the question.

Comment: I think you're right that the output is the same in this case. I would recommend it as the safest option, but I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It is safest, bit just added for the sake of accuracy. But you are right (that's why I +1 it ;))